# Add text to twitter share API via jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, twitter, attr

I can't manage to make jQuery add the content of #quote (which is a paragraph with a string generated via foresmatic API).The full code is here: https://codepen.io/raffaele2692/pen/GvrvxM .... Can you help me? :)

```
<a type="button" class="twitter-share-button"
href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet"
data-size="small"
data-text="">
Tweet</a>


<script>
var textQuote = document.getElementByID("#quote");
$("a").attr("data-text", textQuote);
</script>
```

Comment: var textQuote = document.getElementByID("quote"); or $("#quote)

Answer (score 3):

You have some issues in the js code. You do not need to add "#" to the id for getElementByID call , also to get the text of a HTML element you can use [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method.

```
<script>
var textQuote = $("#quote").text();
$("a").attr("data-text", textQuote);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think textQuote is a HtmlElement object, not the value you want to assign.
you should get the value in quote first.
btw, jquery has a method called data to assign value to data attributes.